# $parse vs $eval ? which one is best practice?

Tags: angularjs

I know that `$parse` and `$eval` both operate on Angular expressions.then why Angular team created these two ?

I checked in angular library, `$eval` is defined like that:

```
$eval: function(expr, locals) {
        return $parse(expr)(this, locals);
      }
```

so what is difference between :

```
$parse(expr)(context, locals);
```

and

```
$eval: function(expr, locals) {
        return $parse(expr)(this, locals);
      }
```

I want to know which one is best practice ? and when to use these two ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you noticed,

```
$parse(expr)($scope, locals)
```

is *exactly* equivalent to

```
$scope.$eval(expr, locals)
```

But, `$parse` is more "fundamental" operation than `$eval`, and so, you could `$parse` once in one place (for example, in `compile` function of a directive):

```
var parsedExpr = $parse(tAttrs.p1);
```

and use repeatedly elsewhere (for example, in a `controller` function)

```
var childScope1 = $scope.$new();
var childScope2 = $scope.$new();

var r1 = parsedExpr(childScope1);
var r2 = parsedExpr(childScope2);
```

Answer (score 20):

I think the important difference is that `$eval` is a `scope` method that executes an expression on the current scope, while `$parse` is a (more globally available) service.

So you can say `$parse(expr)(context, locals);`, with any context, but in the case of `$eval` the `context` will be the `scope`.

Answer (score 2):

$eval behind the scenes uses $parse against the current scope.

Let us say you have

```
$scope.a = 2;
$scope.b = 4;
```

`$parse("a*b")` gives you a function which has to be evaluated against the context/object/scope to get the result.

So now

```
var f = $parse("a*b");
```

`var result = f($scope);` we are using the output of $parse which is a function applied against the $scope.

NOTE:

1. `$eval` always evaluates the expression based on the current scope and returns the result
   Example:   `console.log($scope.$eval("a*b")); // 8`
2. `$parse` just returns the function and does not work on any scope.
   Example:

   ```
   var func = $parse("a*b");
   ```

now `func` can be applied against

1. *any scope*

   ```
   var result = func($scope);
   console.log(result); // 8
   ```
2. *object*

   ```
   var result1 = func({a:3 , b:3});    
   console.log(result1); // 9
   ```

So same expression parsed once can be evaluated against any scope or object.

As said before , for `$eval` angular uses `$parse` against the current scope behind the scenes to evaluate the expression and return the result.

If you want multiple contexts to be executed for the same expression `$parse` is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

“.$eval()” is a simple scope method which takes an expression (and optionally locals) and then executes it against the current scope, using “$parse()”.

The service “$parse()” is where the magic happens. It takes an Angular expression and returns a function, which takes two arguments: “context” and “locals”. The latter is used for overriding variables set in the context. The context is the key part.

```
$scope.foo = 3;
var parseFn = $parse(‘foo = 5’);
parseFn($scope);
$scope.foo; // returns 5
```

or shorter:

```
$scope.foo = 3;
$scope.$eval(‘foo = 5’);
$scope.foo; // returns 5
```